# Facebook Graph API - retrieve basic information and additional variables

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to retireve from Facebook both basic information and additional variables at the same time? For example, using .NET sdk and calling

```
client.Get("me")
```

I will get name, first_name, last_name, etc. and other public information.

I can also run

```
client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,photos" })
```

but this gives me only variables I've asked for, without basic information. Do I need to call it twice? Eventually I could use the second option and ask for all basic fields individually like username, gender, but in this case how to ask for "other public information" as well?

Thanks in advance
Bartek

Answer (score 1):

Your point is interesting. But `/me` only works as a shortcut to quickly get all basic fields at once. You have to override it.

Don't call it twice, since API requests take some time. I advice you to make only one complete request by specifying all the fields you really need.